# Find Laplace transform of a function multiplied by the Dirac delta function

Tags: laplace-transform, dirac-delta

I know that the Laplace transform of the delta function 
$\delta(t-a)$ is $e^{-as}$.

Now my question is to find the Laplace transform of  $te^{-3(t-2)}\delta(t-2) $.

Is there any theorem or easy thumb rule to solve these kinds of problems or should I integrate the function as we conventionally do, to find its Laplace transform?

Comment: $t=(t-2)+2$ lets you split it into two problems and use the shift theorem.

Comment: Yes, that's okay, but how do I find the Laplace transform of $t\delta(t−2)$? I know that I can shift replace $s$ by $s+2$ after finding the Laplace transform.

Comment: @ArjunAshok Also see my other method which is evaluated by your definition of the Laplace transform of the delta function.

Comment: @Ak19 Yes, just saw it. Thank you!

Comment: You're welcome !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the fact that,

> $$\int^{\infty}_0f(t)\delta(t-a)dt=f(a)$$

$$F=\mathcal{L}\{te^{-3(t-2)}\delta(t-2)\}=-\frac{d}{ds}\mathcal{L}\{e^{-3(t-2)}\delta(t-2)\} = -\frac{d}{ds}\int^\infty_0e^{-st}e^{-3(t-2)}\delta(t-2)dt$$

$$F = -e^{6}\frac{d}{ds}\int^\infty_0e^{(-3-s)t}\delta(t-2)dt = -e^6\frac{d}{ds}\bigg[e^{(-3-s)2}\bigg] = -e^6\cdot(-2)e^{-6-2s} = +2e^{-2s}$$

> $$F = 2e^{-2s}$$

**Aliter**

> $$F = \mathcal{L}\{te^{-3(t-2)}\delta(t-2)\} = -\frac{d}{ds}\mathcal{L}\{e^{-3(t-2)}\delta(t-2)\}  = -e^{-6}\frac{d}{ds}\mathcal{L}\{\delta(t-2)\}\bigg\vert_{s\to s+3}$$
>   $$F = -e^{-6}\frac{d}{ds}(e^{-2s})\bigg\vert_{s\to s+3} = -e^{-6}(-2)e^{-2(s+3)} = 2e^{-2s}$$

Answer (score 3):

Use the fact that $f(t) \, \delta(t-a) = f(a) \, \delta(t-a)$:

$$
\mathcal{L}\{te^{-3(t-2)}\delta(t-2)\}
= \mathcal{L}\{2e^{-3(2-2)}\delta(t-2)\} 
= 2 \mathcal{L}\{\delta(t-2)\}
= 2 e^{-2s}.
$$